# What would be the Japanese name of a person with a native Chinese name?

Tags: translation, names, chinese

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When Chinese personal names are written in Japanese in kanji is there always an obvious reading?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3013/when-chinese-personal-names-are-written-in-japanese-in-kanji-is-there-always-an)

What would be the common ways to convert a Chinese name for a person to Japanese?

Would the name be written in the same characters but pronounced like if it was Chinese, for example? Or would the name be entirely written in katakana? If it's the latter, then how would characters with a "ng" in them be converted to katakana like the common surname 杨?