# Adopting a Japanese Name

Tags: kanji, names

すみません, I am trying to adopt a Japanese name. I have a Chinese name written as 吳虎威。 In modern standard Japanese orthography, it would be written as 呉 虎威. I understand that typically, Chinese names are pronounced with the on'yomi readings. For my name, it would be ゴ コイ . However, would it be possible for me to modify the pronunciation of my name?

I know that there is a city in Japan called Kure City (呉市), and 呉 is pronounced くれ. I also know that たけひろ is sometimes written as 威宏, where 威 is pronounced たけ. I also know that 虎, the word for tiger, is often pronounced とら. Could it be possible for me to adopt くれ as my surname? Could it also be possible for me to adopt とらい or こたけ as my given name? What do you think? Do any of those names sound strange to you? Thanks in advance! お願いします!

Comment: Related, perhaps: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56927/9831

Answer (score 1):

I think how to read your given name is up to you. So, mixing on'-yomi and kun'yomi in your name are possible.

Both 虎{とら}威{い} and 虎{こ}威{たけ} should work. Probably giving boy's name as 虎{とら}威{い} will be popular since Rugby World Cup in Japan has been very popular for couple of months this year.

For your surname「呉」, I think it is also up to you though, surname tends to show the roots of your family.

- The inventor of Modern Psychiatry is [呉{くれ} 秀三{しゅうぞう}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%91%89%E7%A7%80%E4%B8%89). His father is [呉{くれ}　黄石{おうせき}](http://www6.plala.or.jp/guti/cemetery/PERSON/K/kure_o.html). Surname was changed from 山田{やまだ} since the family had had residence in 呉{くれ}市 : Kure City for generations from his ancestors.
- The Inventor of Instant Noodle and the founder of  " 日清{にっしん}食品{しょくひん} : Nissin Food Products Co., Ltd. " : 「 [日: 安藤{あんどう}百福{ももふく}, 台 :呉{ウー}百福{バイフゥ}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AE%89%E8%97%A4%E7%99%BE%E7%A6%8F) 」came from Taiwan, his original surname is「呉{ウー}」, but he married to Japanese woman and changed his surname to 安藤{あんどう}.
- [呉{オ} 昇桓{スンファン}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%91%89%E6%98%87%E6%A1%93) is Korean baseball player. He played at Hanshin Taigers in Japan and Major League Baseball in US.
- [Ngô Bảo Châu](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B4%E3%83%BB%E3%83%90%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BB%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%82%A6), Vietnamese Mathematician, is introduced as  吳寶珠 : ゴ・バオ・チャウ.
- [Goh Chok Tong](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B4%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%B3), ex-prime mister in Singapore, is introduced as 呉{ゴー} 作棟{チョクトン}.