# Chinese Name into Japanese

Tags: translation, kanji, names

I was wondering if it was possible to use my Chinese name 安曜輪 Ān Yàolún as a basis for a Japanese name?

The only other option is to use katakana to transcribe my western name, which is one of those Christian names that can be translated into many languages (my first name is the name of the Biblical figure, John the Apostle - 使徒ヨハネ Shito Yohane, who wrote the Gospel of John - ヨハネによる福音書 Yohane ni Yoru Fukuinsho, and my last name is the name of the figure Andrew the Apostle - 使徒アンデレ). So using the Japanese Bible's transcription of my western name, you would get アンデレ ヨハネ Andere Yohane, and I think that sounds kind of awful, which is why I'm thinking of using my Chinese name.  Even using the English name sounds awful, アンドレス ジョン Andoresu Jon.  So I'm hoping to use my Chinese name, 安曜輪 Ān Yàolún.

I have heard that 安達 Adachi is a common Japanese last name, which sounds like a decent way of rendering the monosyllabic Chinese last name 安.  However, I'm not sure how to read 曜輪 in Japanese or if it is even a normal, nice-sounding name.  On the internet I can find references to these different readings, but I'm not sure if any of them sound nice or normal.

曜

- GO-ON and KAN-ON: よう yō
- KUN: ひか hika (like in ひかる hikaru), かがや kagaya (like in ひかる kagayaku)
- NANORI: あき aki, あきら akira, かぐや kaguya, てらす terasu, てる teru, ひかり hikari

輪

- GO-ON and KAN-ON: りん rin (like in 光輪 kōrin "halo, nimbus" or 二輪車
  nirinsha "bike")
- KUN: わ wa (like in 腕輪 udewa "bracelet" or 花輪 hanawa
  "garland, wreath")
- NANORI: なわ nawa, も mo

Is there a natural combination of these names that could sound Japanese and natural, normal-sounding? I'm leaning towards a name with yō, like Yōwa (ようわ) or Yorin (ようりん), but I don't know if they're okay names for men, and which sounds nicer. The name would be:

安達曜輪 - Adachi Yōwa (あだち ようわ)

Is that okay?

Comment: Don't you have to retain アン　ヤオルン which is a direct translation of Ān Yàolún.

Comment: @kimiTanaka Thanks for such a fast response!  I guess I could just turn the Chinese name into Japanese by transcribing it in katakana, but I was wondering if it was possible to have a more natural-sounding name in Japanese.  For this reason, I don't mind changing the 安 (アン) to 安達 (あだち). I thought it was a nice last name when I read about the name あだち in an article from Japanese times. 

https://www.japantimes.co.jp/life/2016/08/08/language/%E5%AE%89-peaceful-character-turbulent-times/

Comment: I disussed [similar one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72870/adopting-a-japanese-name/72875#72875) in the past. Would this be any help for you? 安達 sounds fine. It is up to you in my opinion.

Comment: @kimiTanaka Thank you! I read that previous answer of yours, and it did help. Can I ask what you think of these kun'yomi and nanori readings for 曜輪?  I do not know if they are too strange or too long: ひかわ (Hikawa), かがやわ (Kagayawa), あきなわ (Akinawa), あきも (Akimo), あきらなわ (Akiranawa), あきらも (Akiramo), てるなわ (Terunawa), てるも (Terumo).  Are any of these nice Japanese readings?

Comment: The comment is not where I can answer though, ようわ, あきなわ, てるも would be acceptable for male in my first impression.  Yorin (ようりん) is bit too feminine or strange for the name for you in my opinion.

Comment: @kimiTanaka Thank you so much for your help! :) I will take all that you've said into account.