# How would my Chinese name be translated into Japanese?

Tags: kanji, katakana, names, chinese

My name in chinese is 金辰 (pronounced Jin Chen in mandarin),would I be able to use it properly in Japanese? I know a lot of Chinese names don't work at all, but I'm pretty sure the kanji for mine exists in Japanese, so would it just be converted to Japanese pronunciation, or does that not work? Would it be translated in katakana?

Comment: Duplicate/related: [Can I use my Chinese name as my Japanese name?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56927/can-i-use-my-chinese-name-as-my-japanese-name); [When Chinese personal names are written in Japanese in kanji is there always an obvious reading?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3013/when-chinese-personal-names-are-written-in-japanese-in-kanji-is-there-always-an)