# Can I use my Chinese name as a Japanese name?

Tags: names, chinese

my name is 黃湞鈺 (Huáng Zhēn Yù) with 黃/Huáng as my surname and 湞鈺/Zhēn Yù as my given name, and I'm wondering is it possible to "translate" my Chinese name to a Japanese one? I'm well aware the characters in my name aren't the most common characters Japanese use so is it possible or would it be better to use ステファニー which spells to my English name?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56927/9831 /  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3013/9831 and more: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=Chinese+name

Answer (score 1):

Culturally speaking, we Japanese people do not have a custom to call your name mixing with English name like Stephanie, which sometimes is practiced in other East Asian countries.

If you want yourself to be called "Huáng Zhēn Yù", the name with vowels without any accent and intonation seems easy to pronounce as ファン like :"Fuann" : [不安]{ふあん} , ホアン like "Hoann" : [保安]{ほあん} and ユー like "Yu" as [湯]{ゆ} : "Hot  Water" respectively in Japanese.

(Probably it is important to care about accents and intonations in Chinese Language?)

It is difficult for Japanese to pronounce "Zhēn" as ヂェン. I feel ジェン is easy for Japanese to pronounce like "Jenny" in English Name. But it is up to you, we call チェン (chen)  sometimes. The "z" sound is your matter of taste, so you are the chef to decide flavour.