# How to Convert my Chinese name into Japanese?

Tags: names, chinese

I am Chinese. I want to know how to convert my Chinese name into Japanese. My Chinese is 蓝正吉.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use my Chinese name as my Japanese name?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56927/can-i-use-my-chinese-name-as-my-japanese-name)

Comment: 正吉 is actually a frequent Japanese male name, read Masayoshi. 藍 is a frequent surname, read Ai. If あい　まさよし is an okay option, your name is actually a fully probable Japanese name.