# Is it possible to make a Japanese name from my Chinese name?

Tags: pronunciation, names, chinese

my name is 陳銘聲 in Chinese but i'm not sure how to convert that into a Japanese name. I know there are probably a lot of variations. But I'm just interested in the way Japanese names are created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I translate my Chinese name into Japanese?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65837/how-do-i-translate-my-chinese-name-into-japanese)

Comment: Or https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56927/can-i-use-my-chinese-name-as-my-japanese-name (Sundowner's link doesn't work for me.)