# Translating my name into kanji

Tags: kanji, names

so my first and second name means "peaceful valley", while my surname means "flowers". So all in all my name means "peaceful valley of flowers", "flowers in a peaceful valley", or something like that.

I know flower is hana or 花, but I'm a little lost on what kanjis to use for my first and second name. I know "ya" or "tani" or 谷 means valley, but I don't know what kanji I could use for "peaceful" or "peace".

Also, how would I combine everything in that it would make sense? Sorry, I'm very new to kanji. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello Hana, welcome to Japanese Language Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, your question might be seen by some as 'off-topic' (please see the Community guidelines at https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Secondly, while this isn't an answer to your question directly, you may find this question/answer useful in addressing a more fundamental question, as to whether your name should use kanji at all: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/are-foreign-personal-names-usually-written-in-katakana-rather-than-romaji

Answer (score 1):

平和　means  peace; harmony

source: [平和](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%B9%B3%E5%92%8C)

It has been used in Japanese names if you read it as かず

example: [Kazuyoshi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazuyoshi)